# Rotation and Dragging of an image in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Sir,

In my HTML page, there is an image and two buttons for rotating that image clockwise and anticlockwise directions. And also I need to make draggable that image. I have the codes for doing both dragging and rotation.

I used the following JavaScript for Drag:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#Image1').draggable();
        $('#WaterMark').draggable();
    });
</script>
```

And I used following JavaScript for rotation:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryrotate.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jQueryRotate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var angle = 0;
        $('#btnRotCw').on('click', function () {
            angle += 2;
            $("#Image1").rotate(angle);
        });
        $('#btnRotAcw').on('click', function () {
            angle -= 2;
            $("#Image1").rotate(angle);
        });
    });
</script>
```

But here the rotation is not happening.

Can anyone guide me please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Create a fiddle example please

Comment: Here is http://jsfiddle.net/Dwk3L/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have some problems with your html code or something that you are not showing us. Below is a working fiddle that does what you are expecting your code to do.

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DZH4P/1/)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryrotate.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jQueryRotate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var angle = 0;
        $('#btnRotCw').on('click', function () {
            angle += 2;
            $("#Image1").rotate(angle);
        });
        $('#btnRotAcw').on('click', function () {
            angle -= 2;
            $("#Image1").rotate(angle);
        });
        $('#Image1').draggable();
    });
</script>
```

Avoid loading two separate instances of jQuery as they will conflict with each other.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now its working fine. Thank you very very much for your valuable time.

Answer (score 1):

I dont see any error in your code. I've included a working fiddle along with this.
[Here is a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/68e7T/)

```
$(function () {
        $('#image').draggable();
        $('#image1').draggable();
});

$(document).ready(function () {
        var angle = 0;
        $('#button1').on('click', function () {
            angle += 2;
            $("#image").rotate(angle);
        });
        $('#button2').on('click', function () {
            angle -= 2;
            $("#image").rotate(angle);
        });
    });
```